# Why does attempt to access InnerText property cause Stack Overflow Expection when using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, stack-overflow, html-agility-pack

I'm building an HTML preprocessor using HTMLAgilityPack that builds JSON representations of Html files.  To do this, I'm using a simple **Node** class to contain the necessary properties from the **HtmlNode** objects provided by HtmlAgilityPack.

Unfortunately, I am consistently getting a Stack overflow exception that crashes my program.  It occurs in the last if statement of the **GenerateNode()** method.  As you can see from my code, I have tried unsuccessfully to extract the text from an **HtmlTextNode** and write it to the **Node.InnerText** property of my custom **Node** class. Each of the commented lines throws a stack overflow exception.

For the sake of completeness, I've included all the code in my WebHelpPreprocessor class, but it's only the first code block that concerns this question.

**First Block**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
//
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebHelpPreprocessor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A static class to help process html
    /// </summary>
    public static class Preprocessor
    {
        private static Node GenerateNode(HtmlNode htmlNode)
        {
            Node node = new Node(htmlNode.Name, htmlNode.Attributes["guid"].Value);
            if(htmlNode.Attributes["class"] != null)
            {
                node.Classes = htmlNode.Attributes["class"].Value;
            }
            if(htmlNode.Attributes["id"] != null)
            {
                node.Id = htmlNode.Attributes["id"].Value;
            }
            if(htmlNode.Name == "#text")
            {
                //node.InnerText = htmlNode.InnerHtml;
                //Console.WriteLine(htmlNode.InnerText.Trim());
                //Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(htmlNode));
                Console.WriteLine(htmlNode.Name);

            }
            return node;
        }
```

**Here is the rest of the code**

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Builds a DocumentTree from the root node using breadth-first search
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rootNode">The root node to use for the model</param>
        /// <returns>a completed document tree</returns>
        public static DocumentTree BuildModelBFS(HtmlNode root)
        {
            int nodeCount = 1;
            root.Attributes.Add("guid", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            DocumentTree documentModel = new DocumentTree(new Node(root.Name, root.Attributes["guid"].Value));
            Queue<HtmlNode> q = new Queue<HtmlNode>();

            q.Enqueue(root);
            while (q.Count > 0)
            {
                HtmlNode current = q.Dequeue();
                Node currentNode = documentModel.find(current.Attributes["guid"].Value);
                if (current == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if(current.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    foreach(HtmlNode child in current.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        nodeCount++;
                        child.Attributes.Add("guid", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                        documentModel.AddToTree(GenerateNode(child), currentNode);
                        q.Enqueue(child);
                    }
                }

                //------------------Debugging
                string id;
                if(current.Attributes["id"] != null)
                {
                    id = current.Attributes["id"].Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    id = "0";
                }
                if(current.Name != "#text")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Current node: " + current.Name + " ID: " + id + " Hash Code: " + current.GetHashCode());
                }
                //--------------------End of debugging
            }

            return documentModel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds a DocumentTree from the root node using depth-first search
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rootNode">The root node to use for the model</param>
        /// <returns>a completed document tree</returns>
        public static DocumentTree BuildModelDFS(HtmlNode root)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you get the innerText of htmlNode with `htmlNode.Attributes["value"].Value` instead of accessing it directly?

Comment: I don't believe that there is a **value** attribute for text nodes